# Cannot open database "Life" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user

Tags: c#

I am getting the following in visual studio:

> Cannot open database "Life" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user...

My sqlconnection string is as follows:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Life;Integrated Security=True");
```

What can I do to get this error to be solved.

In SQL Server Management Studio under Security-Studio-Properties under user- User mapping I tick db_owner

SQL Server agent is running

The database is on a local PC and not on a network

Comment: Does your user have the correct permssions on the database?

Comment: Can you connect to \\SQLEXPRESS with the same username/password in SMSS?

Comment: @mxmissile. I can connect with the same username\password in SMSS

Comment: @Charlieface. I am not sure what to do with correct permission on database. Can you tell me where to look please. Thank you

Comment: Then double-check everything. This instance is located on `.` which means the local machine, and is called `SQLEXPRESS` is that what you have in SSMS? You are using Windows Authentication without a username and password, is that what you have in SSMS? Are you connecting to the same database? You would look Users and Roles in SSMS to check if this user has been added for that database, and is part of a role.

Comment: I log in with Windows authentication. I will look at the roles and come back. Have to read up on the roles. In SSMS I can see my database

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that you can check.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/resolve-connectivity-errors-overview
The most likely problems can be solved by making sure you have the correct database name and user name.  Your user name will be `MYPCNAME\MyLoginName` in order to use integrated security

Comment: I have run this "netsh firewall set portopening protocol = TCP port = 1433 name = SQLPort mode = ENABLE scope = SUBNET profile = CURRENT " in the link you send. But got the following
IMPORTANT: Command executed successfully.
However, "netsh firewall" is deprecated;
use "netsh advfirewall firewall" instead.
For more information on using "netsh advfirewall firewall" commands
instead of "netsh firewall", see KB article 947709
at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=121488 .

Ok.
I also added in my antivirus firewall an exception for port 1433 already as well

Comment: I think i found the problem. In visual studio I check my data set and its data source are wrong. Busy try to fix it. Will give feedback if I got it right

Comment: I got it right. It was my connection from visual studio to my database that was incorrect. I today learnt from this. Thank you for the help